# How to filter RecyclerView over different Activity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to filter `RecyclerView` on a new `Activity` and I wonder that how to send parameters back to the `Activity` and notify `RecyclerView` adapter automatically ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the startActivityForResult to start the different activity and pass the filtered value with intent on that different activity

You will get the filtered value in onActivityResult. Set that value on RecyclerView adapter and call notify method will refresh your page